# What is the metre in the Scotch dialect of Thrawn Janet by Robert Louis Stevenson?

Tags: meter, robert-louis-stevenson, dialect

What is the metre of this specific part of dialect: e.g is it iambic, trochaic, spondaic, anapaestic, dactylic?

> Fifty years syne, when Mr. Soulis cam’ first to Ba’weary, he was still a young man––a callant, the folk said—fu’ o’ book-learning’ an’ grand at the exposition, but, as was natural in sae young a man, wi’ nae leevin’ experience in religion. The younger sort were greatly taken wi’ his gifts and his gab; but auld, concerned serious men and woman were moved even to prayer for the young man, whom they took to be a self-deceiver, and the parish that was like to be sae ill-supplied. It was before the days ‘o the moderates––weary fa’ them; but ill things are guid––they baith come bit by bit, a pickle at a time; and there were folk even then that said the Lord had left the college professors to their ain devices, an’ the lads that went to study wi’ them wad hae done mair an’ better sittin’ in a peat-bog, like their forebears of the persecution, wi’ a Bible under their oxter an’ a speerit o’ prayer in their heart.

Comment: Thrawn Janet is a prose story. whereas meter is generally applied to poetry. Is there something that makes you think there should be an identifiable meter in Thrawn Janet?

Comment: That is what I originally thought, but one of my professors referenced to the possibility of metre in dialect such as Scotch as it contrasts so greatly to our English language. When I was trying to identify it 'his gifts and his gab' perhaps stuck out to me as maybe being anapaestic? Identifying metre is not usually my strong point so I just wanted a second opinion if you have one! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not a professor, but my opinion is that no language or dialect has an "inherent" meter unless the writer or speaker puts it there deliberately. While Scots is different enough from English that many consider it a language and not a dialect it is, nevertheless, similar enough to be broadly comprehensible to English speakers. And I can't imagine anyone claiming that the English language has an inherent rhythm.